# How to prevent translated nodes from showing as distinct nodes in Content list in Drupal 7?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have several Movie nodes. When I create a translation of a node, it creates a new distinct Movie with a new nid and the corresponding language.

This is somewhat confusing as I would like the backend user to see a list of distinct movies and not a movie per translation. Is there some way to accomplish this from the administrative side when viewing lists of content?

Comment: This list comes from Views module?

Comment: You could use https://drupal.org/project/entity_translation instead. It translates the content of the fields instead of creating a new node per translation.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the standard localization module that actually displays which records are translations of eachother instead of showing everything as a big list? I was hoping that the user could see at a glance at least which movies are related by translation.

Comment: @Dewayne maybe https://drupal.org/project/translation_overview could be helpful in your case?